# Nodemon: app crashed waiting for file changes before starting

Tags: node.js

Node version: v16.6.0 NPM version: 8.5.0

I have followed some steps to solve this issue and that is given below.

Open Windows Task Manager is given in the attached file
End Task (Node.js JavaScript Runtime) But the problem is not solved!
Here is the code of server.js

```
import * as express from 'express';
import * as bodyParser from 'body-parser';
import 'reflect-metadata';
import * as cors from 'cors';
import * as swaggerUi from 'swagger-ui-express';
import * as swaggerJSDoc from 'swagger-jsdoc';
import * as lodash from 'lodash';
import * as path from 'path';
import * as fs from 'fs';
import * as logger from 'morgan';
import * as dotenv from 'dotenv';
import * as http from 'http';
import * as AgendaInstance from 'agenda';
import * as AgendashInstance from 'agendash';

import initGlobalVariables from './constants';
import HttpResponse from './services/response';
import CustomResponse from './services/response/customResponse';
import * as logrotate from 'logrotator';
import Agenda from './services/agenda';
// Import passport strategies
import passportStrategies from './config/passport';
import {helpers} from './utils';

/** Rotation is based on copying the file contents and then truncating the file size to 0.
 *  This way we avoid file renaming problems where programs are not always prepared to handle a log file being renamed.
 */
const rotator = logrotate.rotator;

// Load environment variables from .env file
dotenv.config();

(async () => {
    // Init global variables
    await initGlobalVariables();

    // Create Express server
    const app = express();

    // Express configuration
    app.all('/*', function (req, res, next) {
        res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
        next();
    });

    // Request body parser
    app.use(bodyParser.json());
    app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: true}));

    // Enable CORS
    app.use(cors());

    // Middleware to check tenant code
    // app.use(async (req, res, next) => {
    //     let tenantCode = req.get('code');
    //     if (tenantCode) {
    //         // Update current connection by the new one
    //         // NOTE THAT SWITCHING TENANT DB WILL AFFECT TO ALL REQUEST FROM NOW ON
    //         await global.mongoInstances['default'].updateCurrentConnectionByTenantCode(
    //             tenantCode, global.connections['default']);

    //         // Re init model base on the new connection
    //         global.mongoModel = initModel(global.connections.currentTenantConnection);
    //     }

    //     next();

    // });

    // Import public routers
    const initPublicRouter = await import('./routes');
    initPublicRouter(app);

    // Set template engine
    app.set('views', 'src/views');
    app.set('view engine', 'hbs');

    /*///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
      /////                   START LOGS CONFIG                  /////
      ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////*/

    // For production, access logs keep all logs about http requests, including error logs
    if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'development') {
        // Create log directory
        const logDirectory = path.resolve('logs');
        fs.existsSync(logDirectory) || fs.mkdirSync(logDirectory);

        // Define directory to write access logs
        const logPath = path.join(process.cwd(), '/logs/access.log');
        const accessLogStream = fs.createWriteStream(logPath, {flags: 'a'});
        app.use(logger('combined', {stream: accessLogStream}));

        // Check file rotation every 30 minutes, and rotate the file if its size exceeds 10 mb.
        // Keep only 3 rotated files and compress (gzip) them.
        rotator.register(logPath, {schedule: '30m', size: '10m', compress: true, count: 3});
        rotator.on('error', function (err) {
            logger('Oops, an error occured!');
        });

        // 'rotate' event is invoked whenever a registered file gets rotated
        rotator.on('rotate', function (file) {
            logger('File ' + file + ' was rotated!');
        });
    }

    // Show method, url, status , response time, res content length in console log
    app.use(logger('dev'));

    /*///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
      /////                    END LOGS CONFIG                  /////
      ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////*/

    /*///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
      /////                 START SWAGGER CONFIG                  /////
      ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////*/

    const swaggerDefinition = {
        info: {
            // API informations (required)
            title: 'Home Key APIs', // Title (required)
            version: '1.0.0', // Version (required)
        },
        basePath: '/api', // Base path (optional),
        securityDefinitions: {
            // Enable api key in header, using security: - auth: [] in jsdoc to enable check this
            auth: {
                type: 'apiKey',
                in: 'header',
                name: 'Authorization',
            },
        },
    };

    const filenameExtension = process.env.NODE_ENV === 'local' ? 'ts' : 'js';
    const basePath = process.env.NODE_ENV === 'local' ? './src/' : './build/';
    const lookupFolders = [path.join(basePath, 'controllers'), path.join(basePath, 'models')];

    let swaggerApis = [];

    //General path to lookup swagger define
    lodash.forEach(lookupFolders, lookupFolder => {
        const directories = helpers.getDirectories(lookupFolder);

        lodash.forEach(directories, directory => {
            swaggerApis.push(path.join(directory, `*.${filenameExtension}`));
        });
    });

    let options = {
        swaggerDefinition,
        apis: swaggerApis, // <-- not in the definition, but in the options
    };

    const swaggerSpec = swaggerJSDoc(options);

    app.use('/api-docs', swaggerUi.serve, swaggerUi.setup(swaggerSpec));

    /*///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
      /////                  END SWAGGER CONFIG                  /////
      ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////*/

    /*///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
      /////             START AGENDA DASHBOARD CONFIG             /////
      ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////*/

    // Init agenda instance
    const agenda = new AgendaInstance({
        db: {
            address: global.configs.agenda.dbUri,
            collection: 'scheduleJobs',
            options: {
                useNewUrlParser: true,
            },
        },
    });
    // Serve agenda dashboard
    app.use('/agenda/dashboard', AgendashInstance(agenda));

    /*///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
      /////               END AGENDA DASHBOARD CONFIG             /////
      ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////*/

    // Init Passport
    passportStrategies(app);

    /*///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
      /////                 START CORS MIDDLEWARE                 /////
      ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////*/

    app.use(function (req, res, next) {
        let value = req.get('referer');

        if (!value) {
            value = req.get('origin');
        }

        res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials', 'true');
        res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET,PUT,POST,DELETE');
        res.header(
            'Access-Control-Allow-Headers',
            'Origin, Content-Type, Authorization, REST-API-KEY-HEADER, x-auth-token, switch-company-code',
        );

        // intercept OPTIONS method
        if ('OPTIONS' === req.method) {
            res.sendStatus(200);
        } else {
            next();
        }
    });

    /*///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
      /////                 END CORS MIDDLEWARE                 /////
      ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////*/

    /*///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
      /////                   START STATIC PATH                  /////
      ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////*/

    app.use(express.static(path.resolve('public')));
    app.use(express.static(path.resolve('src/views')));

    app.use('/images/', express.static(path.resolve('public/images')));

    // Test socket client
    app.get('/socketClient', function (req, res) {
        res.sendFile(path.join(process.cwd(), '/public/socketClient.html'));
    });

    /*///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
      /////                    END STATIC PATH                   /////
      ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////*/

    // Catch 404 and forward to error handler
    app.use(function (req, res, next) {
        // Normalize error format
        let error = HttpResponse.returnErrorWithMessage(`Not found: ${req.method} ${req.originalUrl}`);
        // Set error status code
        res.status(404);
        // Pass to the next middleware
        next(error);
    });

    // Step 1:  Write error logs file in production mode
    if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'development') {
        app.use((err, req, res, next) => {
            next(err);
        });
    }

    // Step 2: Return meaningful error, so there is no stack traces leaked to user
    app.use(function (err, req, res, next) {
        if (err instanceof CustomResponse && res.statusCode !== null) {
            res.json(err);
        } else {
            // Set error status code
            res.status(500);
            HttpResponse.returnInternalServerResponseWithMessage(res, err.message);
        }
    });

    // Create http server with express
    const httpServer = http.createServer(app);

    // Start Express server
    httpServer.listen(process.env.PORT || 3000, () => {
        console.log('  App is running at http://localhost:%d in %s mode', process.env.PORT || 3000, app.get('env'));
        console.log('  Press CTRL-C to stop\n');
    });

    // Allow maximum 20 mongo connection listener
    process.setMaxListeners(20);

    // Init agenda
    global.agendaInstance = new Agenda();
})();
```

[image]

I'm new to MEAN so am I missing something here that is causing the crash? Any ideas?

Comment: try adding a folder or directory in which you are trying to write files into nodemon ignore which will ignore any changes that occur on that directory and app will not crash